# Gerar páginas únicas para cliente efetuar pagamento

Tags: php

Possuo um sistema em que o cliente digita 5 parâmetros e ao clicar em <kbd>enviar</kbd> é direcionado para uma outra página onde as informações preenchidas na tela anterior são postadas.

Porém hoje essa página de destino é sempre a mesma. O que eu preciso é que cada vez que eu digitar as informações elas fossem postadas para uma URL diferente e única e que mantivesse os valores postados para serem acessados depois.

Em resumo esses valores postados são os dados de pagamento de um *gateway*, e preciso que cada vez que o admin entrar e digitar um valor, seja gerado um link para ele enviar a cada cliente para o mesmo efetuar o pagamento.

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia gerar esses links usando o id do cliente, ou o id desse pagamento que tem na sua base de dados para gerar um link unico.

A maneira mais simples seria uma query string no URL com o tipo de funcionalidade, e com o id da fatura. Por exemplo:

```
dominio.com/?tipo=pagamento&fatura=10
```

ou mais simples:

```
dominio.com/?pagamento=10 // assim tem o tipo na chave e o id no valor
```

Se quiser pode também encriptar a query string, mas parece-me desnecessário aqui.

Usando o meu segundo exemplo podia usar assim para saber no PHP os dados do url:

```
<?php
if($fatura = $_GET["pagamento"]){
    echo $fatura; // dá 10
    // usar esse valor para o que precisa
}
?>
```

Comment: Boa Sergio. Consegui gerar a URL postando via GET ao invés de POST. Mas como postei todos os parâmetros a URL ficou gigante. Tem alguma idéia de como eu posso fazer para gerar  automaticamente um link reduzido com essa url   http://site.com.br/index.php?lojaID=1&valor_pedido=10000&pedidoID=ABC122&maximo_parcelas=6&ambiente=Teste&x=33&y=15 ?